# Errors using MATLAB function "errorbar"

Tags: matlab

I'm having difficulty using errorbar. I have a line, `y = theta`, and I want to plot errorbars along it. I have a vector of errors named `momeerr95`. I attempted using `errorbar` but when using the line of code `errorbar(theta, momeerr95)`, I get an error back saying "X, Y, and error bars all must be the same length.".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are your variable dimensions? Symmetric or asymmetric error?

Comment: Post a small example including definition of all variables

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `errorbar` with two values, `errorbar(Y,E)`. Here `E` has to be a symetric error of the same size as Y. As you have an asymetric error, you have to split up `E` into `L` and `U`, the lower and upper error and call `errorbar(X,Y,L,U)`. As you don't have an `X`, set it to `X=1:numel(Y)`